# Disable single Firefox Hot Key

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

I would like to disable the hot key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> in Firefox, which currently closes all tabs.

Since the recent version came out with the feature to group tabs, I have been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to show all tab groups.

I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> too many times!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install ***keyconfig*** from [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994) (click on the the very first word that has a link and accept to install it from an unknown location) - it works even on FF 8.0 beta.

To use it, turn on the menu bar (if just temporarily) with right click on the toolbars and check **Menu bar**, and run keyconfig from Tools >  Keyconfig, find the **Close Window**  command and hit **Disable**. You don't have to restart Firefox and you can turn off the menu bar if you want to.

[image: keyconfig window]